# JTree : Check the level of selection

Tags: java, swing, jtree, mouselistener

I am using MouseAdapter to check for double clicks on JTree nodes. I want to have some different action depending on the level of the node selected. How can I check the level of node ? Here is the code for the listener:

```
private MouseAdapter getMouseAdapter(JTree jtree) {
        final JTree tree = jtree;
        return new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                TreePath selPath = tree.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (selPath != null) {
                    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                        String selectedNode = selPath.getLastPathComponent().toString();

              // >>>>>  check on which level of the tree this node is        
                    }
                }
            }};
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the length of the path from `selPath` to the tree root by first calling the [getPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html#getPath%28%29) method of `selPath` and computing its length.

```
Object[] array = selPath.getPath();
int depth = array.length;
```

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).

Answer (score 1):

```
TreePath path = tree.getSelectionPath();
int level = path.getPathCount();
```

See the [TreePath manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Shahriar. Please read the FAQ for tips on how to markup code blocks so that they are formatted properly, and also consider adding an explanation for your solutions to help people understand what you have done.